# Using pmap on a subset of columns

Tags: r, purrr

I have three list columns in a tibble: `x`, `left`, and `right`.  Very simply, I want to know if the element in the jth position of `x` is between the jth elements of `left` and `right`.  Here is some code I have written so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(binom)


params = crossing(p = seq(0.05,0.5,0.05), size = 10:100, n = 50)

simulation.results = params %>% 
                      mutate(x = pmap(., rbinom)) %>% 
                      select(-n) %>% 
                      mutate(left = map2(x,size,~binom.agresti.coull(.x,.y)$lower),
                             right = map2(x,size, ~binom.agresti.coull(.x,.y)$upper),
                             coverage = pmap_lgl(list(x = x, left = left, right = right), between) #Problem here
                             )
```

I keep getting the error

```
#> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots): Evaluation error: Expecting a single value: [extent=50]..
```

though I am sure I am using the syntax correctly.  A smaller example seems to work

```
library(tidyverse)

x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(4,5,6)
z = c(2,3,4)

pmap_lgl(list(x = x,left = y, right = z), between)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

How can I determine which elements of `x` are between `left` and `right` using `purrr`?  What have I done wrong and how can I avoid it in the future?

Comment: You can check the 'left' and 'right'  It is not a single value for each row.  For `between`, the 'left' and 'right' should be of length 1

Comment: If you need to check for each corresponding element `params %>% mutate(x = pmap(., rbinom)) %>% select(-n) %>% mutate(left = map2(x, size, ~  binom.agresti.coull(.x, .y)$lower), right = map2(x,size, ~binom.agresti.coull(.x,.y)$upper), coverage = pmap(list(x, left, right), ~ ..1 > ..2 & ..1 < ..3))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns 'x', 'left' and 'right' are `list` columns with each element length > 1, but `between` 'left' and 'right' argument takes only a vector of length 1.  In order to make it, we can either expand the dataset by `unnest`ing the `list` elements and then apply the `pmap`

```
params %>%
  mutate(x = pmap(., rbinom)) %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  mutate(left = map2(x, size, ~  
                      binom.agresti.coull(.x, .y)$lower), 
         right = map2(x,size,  ~
                       binom.agresti.coull(.x,.y)$upper)) %>%
  unnest %>% 
  mutate(coverage = pmap_lgl(list(x, left, right), between))
```

---

Or instead of using `between` we can use the comparison operators while keeping the `list` structure

```
params %>% 
   mutate(x = pmap(., rbinom)) %>%
   select(-n) %>% 
   mutate(left = map2(x, size, ~
               binom.agresti.coull(.x, .y)$lower), 
          right = map2(x,size, ~
               binom.agresti.coull(.x,.y)$upper), 
          coverage = pmap(list(x, left, right), ~ ..1 > ..2 & ..1 < ..3)
```

Comment: can you explain the double dots? Is there documentation on this syntax?

Comment: @Nettle It is the syntax for extracting the arguments.  Here `..1` implies each element of 'x', `..2` for `left` and `..3` for right

Comment: Understood...instead of  `.x` and `.y`, because we'd eventually run out of letters with `pmap`

Comment: @Nettle `pmap` is a more generalized version of `map` where it can take more than one argument.   (`map2` takes two).  If there are many argumentts, instead of `..1`, `..2` etc. can concatenate it `c(...) %>%` and then do the processing based on the requirement

Comment: @user63230 Do you want me to check the linked post

Comment: @user63230 i posted a solution there.